# How can I instantiate after retrieving data?

Tags: ios, swift

I am retrieving data from my database, and using a struct to handle the object. I need to access `newObj` below, but the image is `nil`. When I print the image in the conversion from data to a `UIImage`, the image exists, but when I print it under the `.getDataInBackground` it is nil. I'm guessing that I have to put it inside the block or run it on a synchronous thread? What is the proper way to handle this?

```
var pic = UIImage()
pic.getDataInBackground(block: { (data: Data?, error: Error?) in
    if(error == nil){
        let newPic = UIImage(data: data!)
        if(newPic != nil){
            pic = newPic!
            print("inside block \(pic)") //returns data
        }
    }else{
        print(error)
    }
})
print(pic) // returns 0

let newObj = Obj(name: "Bob", pic: pic)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getDataInBackground` closure is running on the background thread, and will take some time, the code right after the closure is executed *before* the closure is called so pic hasn't had a chance to be initialized yet.

In your current code, the order of print statements should be:

```
UIImage() // via `print(pic)`
inside block UIImage() // via `print("inside block \(pic)")`
```

You probably want to create your `newObj` within the scope of the closure like this:

```
pic.getDataInBackground(block: { (data: Data?, error: Error?) in
    // #3 0.25s
    if(error == nil){
        let newPic = UIImage(data: data!)
        if(newPic != nil){
            pic = newPic!
            print("inside block \(pic)")

            let newObj = Obj(name: "Bob", pic: pic)

            // pass the new object back to the main queue through 
            // a method
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                collectObj(newObj)
            }

        }
    }
    else{
        print(error)
    }
})
```